# MySQL запрос внутри REDBean

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm, redbeanphp

Всем привет, срочно нужна помощь.
Я использую RedBeanPHP, и пока не понимаю до конца как делать запросы внутри него.

Мне нужно сделать следующий запрос из БД.

Найти все записи, где `id` динамичен, и отсортировать по дате.

Как это будет выглядеть.

Код ниже не работает

```
$hints = R::findAll('comments', 'ORDER BY data AND string_id = ?', array($text->id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getFindAll($id)
{
    $query = R::findAll('comments', 'string_id = '. $id .' ORDER BY data');
    return $query;
}
```